# Writing Arabic in a Netbeans Web Application

Tags: html, web-applications, netbeans, utf-8

I'm using "Netbeans Web Application" to make a simple page that contains Arabic words

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="height1" name="height1" value="" align="right"/>= الطول <br/>
```

I added a tag in the beginning of the page that contains page encoding `UTF-8` 
and it doesn't make any thing.

before I was using Notepad++ with this tag

```
<charset=Windows-1256">
```

it is work right, but trying it in Netbeans .. still make nothing

Comment: So what is the question? How to tune NetBeans to save the file in UTF-8 or what?

Comment: Make sure your document is actually encoded as UTF-8 before specifying that it is UTF-8.

Comment: if u know the " Arabic " language encoded under which encoder ?? tell me :)